# Questions answered in comments

Tags: discussion, answers, unanswered-questions, comments

What the process for having a comment "moved" so it can be classified as the answer.  For example on this post:

[Cannot get audiences to work with LdapRoleProvider](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3795/cannot-get-audiences-to-work-with-ldaproleprovider)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, moderators can't convert the comment to an answer. This leaves us with two options:

1. Request that the OP post the comment in an answer
2. Post the answer ourselves and make the answer a community wiki

Comment: At least I have a path to follow when I find these.